# Is it possible to install Debian within a Windows filesystem in the same manner as Ubuntu can be installed with Wubi?

Tags: windows, partitioning, debian, multi-boot

I have a Windows 7 laptop whose hard drive has four primary partitions out of the box.

The first partition is labeled "SYSTEM" (209 MB NTFS) and seems to contain the Windows boot loader.
The second partition is labeled "NTFS" (237 GB NTFS) which is obviously the main Windows partition.
The third partition is labeled "RECOVERY" (13 GB NTFS) which I can only assume contains the factory recovery tools and data.
The forth partition is labeled "HP_TOOLS" (108 MB FAT), probably has something to do with the diagnostic tools that can be set to run after POST.

I would like to be able to dual-boot Windows 7 and Debian on this laptop. Normally I would resize the main Windows partition to make space for Debian but because a hard drive has a limit of four primary partitions, I can't add a fifth partition for the Debian installation.

I could delete either the RECOVERY or HP_TOOLS partition and resize and move the remaining three partitions to allow space for an extended partition into which I could create logical partitions for a Debian installation but I really don't want to that.

I already have Ubuntu installed on this laptop using Wubi to create the Ubuntu partitions as files within the Windows 7 partition, which works very well.

Is there a tool available like Wubi that will allow me to do the same with Debian?